# Naturalized obtain visas equals natives?

Tags: visas

A naturalized American citizen (or country of the European Union) has some limitation to obtain visas to other countries?

Comment: How would a visa-issuing country even know whether an applicant is naturalized?

Comment: @phoog: They could ask.  Also, some passports might contain an indication.  For instance, US passports list the holder's place of birth; if it's not within the US, you could guess that the holder might be a naturalized citizen (though they could also have been born abroad to US parents).

Comment: @NateEldredge my point exactly.  The cost of keeping trackof every country's citizenship laws would be prohibitive.  Besides, a US citizen born in the US could have been the child of a diplomat, and subsequently naturalized.

Answer (score 3):

Various visa application forms require the traveler to list all citizenships, as well as things like previous visa rejections or criminal convictions. So unless the traveler is lying -- a **very** bad idea -- the consular officials will know.

And I believe that both the US and EU apply special scrutiny to travelers born in some countries perceived as high risk, regardless of their current citizenship. (Whether that is justified or not belongs on the politics SE site.)

---

**Follow-Up:** Check the recently proposed  changes to the US visa waiver program: [BBC - US House votes to restrict visa-free travel after Paris attacks](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-35047716)

Comment: How do they apply scrutiny if the naturalized foreign-born traveller doesn't require a visa ?

Comment: @blackbird57, there may be immigration interviews even if no visa are required. Check e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_System_for_Travel_Authorization

Answer (score 3):

Normally it does not matter.  However, it can.  Try getting a visa to a bunch of Arab nations with a place of birth of "Jerusalem"!  (Even if you were the child of a diplomat stationed there.)

Comment: If your place of birth was outside Jerusalem at the time of birth, and later annexed, [you can have the old name listed](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/94675.pdf) on your passport as the place of birth.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not the one that had the problem.  I encountered someone online that had run into it.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at some visa applications that asked for nationality-at-birth. And in the case of people who hold dual citizenship, whether they know or want it or not, they may not even need a visa to visit a country which thinks they are still a citizen.